# SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, jwt, token, access-token

In an ASP.NET Core 5 project with RestAPI, I'm using JWT Bearer with tokens and refresh-tokens. I configured the startup like this:

```
var jwtSecretKey = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSecretKey);

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    SaveSigninToken = true,
    ValidateActor = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
    // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
});
```

For generating the Tokens I used this code (Something to notice is I used **UTC** dates):

```
string validIssuer = _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
string validAudience = _configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
var jwtSecretKey = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Jwt:Key");
var issuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSecretKey));
var accessTimeout = _configuration.GetValue<int>("Jwt:MinutosExpiracionTokenAcceso");

DateTime fechaHoy = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime fechaExpiracionToken = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(accessTimeout);

var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) // (JWT ID) Unique Identifier for JWT, can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed. Is best suited for refresh tokens
};

foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
}

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    validIssuer,
    validAudience,
    claims,
    fechaHoy,
    fechaExpiracionToken,
    new SigningCredentials(issuerSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
);

var refreshTimeout = _configuration.GetValue<int>("Jwt:MinutosExpiracionTokenAutorizacion");

var refreshToken = new RefreshToken()
{
    JwtId = token.Id,
    IsUsed = false,
    UserId = user.Id,
    AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    ExpiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(refreshTimeout),
    IsRevoked = false,
    Token = RandomString(25) + Guid.NewGuid()
};

await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<RefreshToken>().AddAsync(refreshToken);
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

var tokensDto = new TokensResponseDto
{
    Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
    RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token
};

return tokensDto;
```

I'm facing issues validating the token (_tokenValidationParameters are the same as used in startup):

```
var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
SecurityToken validatedToken = null;

principal = jwtTokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenRequest.Token, _tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

It's throwing the mentioned exception with no specific dates, no matter whether I use localtime such as DateTime.Now instead of UTC.

I tried by adding LifetimeValidator in TokenValidationParameters in startup like this:

```
LifetimeValidator = (DateTime? notBefore, 
                     DateTime? expires, 
                     SecurityToken securityToken, 
                     TokenValidationParameters validationParameters
                    ) => 
                    {
                        if (expires != null)
                        {
                            if (DateTime.UtcNow < expires.Value.ToUniversalTime())
                            {
                                return true; // Still valid
                            }
                        }

                        return false; // Expired
                    }
```

However, ValidateToken fails with this exception:

IDX10230: Lifetime validation failed. Delegate returned false, securitytoken: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. My server (generating token) time and my client (consuming token) time were different. Synchronized and worked perfectly.

Comment: how did you Synchronized, can you please explain?

Comment: Change the system time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I deployed the application on one of the Linux server, I had a similar "IDX10222" error, The reason behind this error is that the server current time is running behind the token creation time, so server is unable to validate the token.

For Example - Token Creation Time - 10:00:00 on dd:MM:yyyy   UTC,
Linux Server Time   - 08:00:00 on dd:MM:yyyy   UTC

Then we get this error - Lifetime validation failed. The token is not yet valid.

Please check your machine datetime and fix if it is not in sync with the current time.

Answer (score -2):

You Try:

```
/*
ClaimsPrincipal principal = null;
principal = jwtTokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenRequest.Token, _tokenValidationParameters, out validatedToken);
*/

validatedToken = jwtTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

/*Your own validation logic*/
```